# How can I fix the error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, syntax-error

I coded a table in Python and I need to create a new column that count the number of `s`.

This is my code:

```
new_dic={'animal':list(sequence_dict.keys()),'info':list(sequence_dict.values())}
    table=pd.DataFrame(new_dic,columns=['animal','info'])
    table['S']=table.info.str.count('S')
```

But the code raises an error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

`info()` is a built-in Pandas dataframe method, so `table.info` is that method, and you can't refer to the column using attribute syntax. Use indexing instead.

```
table['S']=table['info'].str.count('S')
```